# circleci failed when installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm, circleci

im kinda new in using circleci

i got `#unloaded = false` error when try to install other node version using `node/install`

[image: error image]

im using this orbs :

[image: orbs and circleci version]

Comment: Use latest version of node , if you do not have a restriction with node version sample 

Example: 

        node: circleci/node@4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got fix by using newer circle-ci orbs